# Is 200 MHz DRAM Frequency (by speccy) the max frequency my ram is able to work at?

Tags: memory, ddr2, ddr

Is it possible that my settings are wrong? (single channel 6 Gb (as much as possible)) I've researched and found that everything as it should be. Am I wrong?

`Memory slots
    Total memory slots  4
    Used memory slots   3
    Free memory slots   1
Memory
    Type    DDR2
    Size    6144 MBytes
    Channels #  Single
    DRAM Frequency  200.9 MHz
    CAS# Latency (CL)   6 clocks
    RAS# to CAS# Delay (tRCD)   6 clocks
    RAS# Precharge (tRP)    6 clocks
    Cycle Time (tRAS)   18 clocks
    Bank Cycle Time (tRC)   25 clocks
    Command Rate (CR)   2T
Physical Memory
    Memory Usage    83 %
    Total Physical  6.00 GB
    Available Physical  1.01 GB
    Total Virtual   15 GB
    Available Virtual   8.29 GB
SPD
    Number Of SPD Modules   3
        Slot #1
            Type    DDR2
            Size    1024 MBytes
            Manufacturer    Samsung
            Max Bandwidth   PC2-6400 (400 MHz)
            Part Number M3 78T2953EZ3-CF7
            Serial Number   2033736592
            Week/year   51 / 07
                Timing table
                        Frequency   CAS# Latency    RAS# To CAS#    RAS# Precharge  tRAS    tRC Voltage
                    JEDEC #1    266.7 MHz   4.0 4   4   12  16  1.800 V
                    JEDEC #2    333.3 MHz   5.0 5   5   15  20  1.800 V
                    JEDEC #3    400.0 MHz   6.0 6   6   18  24  1.800 V
        Slot #2
            Type    DDR2
            Size    4096 MBytes
            Manufacturer    Samsung
            Max Bandwidth   PC2-6400 (400 MHz)
            Part Number M3 95T5160QZ4-CF7
            Serial Number   2890263646
            Week/year   14 / 12
                Timing table
                        Frequency   CAS# Latency    RAS# To CAS#    RAS# Precharge  tRAS    tRC Voltage
                    JEDEC #1    266.7 MHz   4.0 4   4   12  16  1.800 V
                    JEDEC #2    333.3 MHz   5.0 5   5   15  20  1.800 V
                    JEDEC #3    400.0 MHz   6.0 6   6   18  24  1.800 V
        Slot #3
            Type    DDR2
            Size    1024 MBytes
            Manufacturer    Samsung
            Max Bandwidth   PC2-6400 (400 MHz)
            Part Number M3 78T2953EZ3-CF7
            Serial Number   2033736598
            Week/year   51 / 07
                Timing table
                        Frequency   CAS# Latency    RAS# To CAS#    RAS# Precharge  tRAS    tRC Voltage
                    JEDEC #1    266.7 MHz   4.0 4   4   12  16  1.800 V
                    JEDEC #2    333.3 MHz   5.0 5   5   15  20  1.800 V
                    JEDEC #3    400.0 MHz   6.0 6   6   18  24  1.800 V`

Comment: No, I mean these rows:     Channels #  Single
    DRAM Frequency  200.9 MHz

Comment: It shouldn't be a 400MHz, right?

Comment: I mean it is really works at JEDEC #3    400.0 MHz   6.0 6   6   18  24  1.800 V and speccy just sjows half of frequency because DDR can send data at twice rate as frequency. Some speccy related issue, not my RAM settings.